# How to make a circular view pager2?

Tags: java, android-studio, slider, infinite-scroll, android-viewpager2

How can I make a circular view pager2(infinite-scrolling) in java? for example I wanna go from page 1to page 100 while swiping left and not to get stopped.

```
myViewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
            Log.d(CPAct,"onPageScrolled "+position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            Log.d(CPAct,"onPageSelected Position: "+position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            Log.d(CPAct,"onPageScrollStateChanged  state: "+state);
          
            if (state == ViewPager2.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                if (myViewPager2.getCurrentItem() == 0)
                    myViewPager2.setCurrentItem(99, false);
                else if (myViewPager2.getCurrentItem() == 99) 
                    myViewPager2.setCurrentItem(0, false);
            }
```

I tried the code above in initView() after setting adapter but it doesn't work properly. for example when I swipe left from page 2, it directly goes to the last page and page 1 is skipped .The same thing happens when I swipe right to get to the last page and it directly goes to page 1. I just wanna make an infinite scrolling without skipping any pages.

Comment: Are you using android studio?

Comment: show your code what you've done and what is your problem exacly

Comment: yes I am using android studio. @KrzysztofWitkowski

Comment: here is my code. please take a look. @snachmsm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should post `Adapter`s code, in there you should return `Integer.MAX_VALUE` in `getCount` and introduce proper fetching model for drawing list item - e.g. if you have `ArrayList data` then use `data.get(position % data.getItemCount())` in `getItem` (as array have fixed size, but you are informing adapter about veeery large/infinite number of items)

your current aproach isn't good, as you are manipulating `View`s positions, this for shure will add some visual glitches sooner or later, and also is not very efficient

Comment: thank you.I made these changes to my adapter and it worked for when I go from last page to first one but when the app starts on very first page it does not work and I can not get to swipe it to left. Could you please explain about data.getItemCount. Is that meaning the size of array or the position of a specified item. and also please explain about getItem. where it exactly is?Am I supposed to use it in overriden createFragment method?

Comment: yes, exacly, as [DOCs](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration#adapter-methods) says. about swiping left at the beggining - just set `Integer.MAX_VALE/2 - (Integer.MAX_VALUE/2) % realPagesCount` page position as initial (`setCurrentItem(middlePagePosition, false)` - `false` for `smoothScroll`)

Comment: `getItemCount` informs adapter how much items/pages are there, you should fake that there is very big amount of data there. then `createFragment` may be called with very high `position` param, so you should pick proper page for position using `%` (older adapters have `getItem` method)

Comment: Your response was very helpful to me and I finally did it :) You explained very clearly and I really appreciate it. thanks a lot

Comment: consider upvoting/accepting answer if helpful :) good luck!

Comment: I had upvoted your response but as I dont have enough reputation, my score wont be shown to public. And this was my first activity in stackoverflow so I didnt know "accepting an answer" but now I did it.Thank you anyway